# error while writing ffmpeg command for changing bit rate of mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg commands to change audio bit rate and video bit rate of one .mp4 file while creating one new .mp4 file. I am wirting the command as:---

ffmpeg -i oldFile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -ab 128 -b 700 newFile.mp4

here: oldFile.mp4 == old file, whose audio bit rate and video bit rate i want to change. But I am getting this error:

"encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results. Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it."...
Now kindly tell me if u know that what should be the correct command for this requirement. waiting for reply.

---

Thanks for your advise.
now I am writing this command as:--

**ffmpeg -i oldFile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -ab 128k -b 700k newFile.mp4**

but this time I am getting error as:- "**Too many bits per frame requested**"

But the same command is working if I am trying to change the bit rate of an older avi file while making a new avi file.

can you please tell me what is the cause of error...
your help is appreciable.

waiting for reply.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html it appears that you need to specify the K after your bitrates.

```
ffmpeg -i oldFile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -ab 128**k** -b 700**k** newFile.mp4
```

Comment: Hi bitfed,
Thanks for your advise.Please guide me a bit more.now I am writing this command as:--

ffmpeg -i oldFile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -ab 128k -b 700k newFile.mp4

but this time I am getting error as:- "Too many bits per frame requested"
But the same command is working if I am trying to change the bit rate of an older avi file while making a new avi file.
can you please tell me what is the cause of error...
your help is appreciable.

waiting for reply.

Comment: I tried this exact command-line string on a video I had and it didn't give me any error (Edit: I receive an error: "[mpeg4 @ 01C98F80] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected". This is due to the source file and the decoding..but has no real effect on the success of the output)  Have you tried it with any other video files?  It might be your source file.

Comment: I also just noticed that your "-b 700" switch doesn't have the k either.  I don't think this really matters for your problem though, but the documentation shows it used that way.

Comment: yeh Thanks bitfed for your reply.I have tried with another .mp4 format video, it is the same error. but with .avi video the same command string is working fine.My actual requirement is that I want to change bascially 3 things:(1) Bit rate to 1000 kbps (2) level to 3.0 then (3) profile to Baseline while encoding. so can u please tell me the exact command line string which i should write for encoding my older .mp4 file into newer .mp4 file. waiting for your reply..

Comment: I would use Handbrake.  It's cross platform, and has a handbrakeCLI executable that I've never had an issue with when scripting, etc.  http://handbrake.fr/